# How to enable gzip for yii2?

Tags: .htaccess, yii, yii2

I need to add new rules to .htaccess or to add the code to index.php of YII2?

My site is on shared hosting.

I want to compress only .css and .js files. I don't want to compress all responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it work by attaching event handler on yii\web\Response in index.php.

```
$application = new yii\web\Application($config);
$application->on(yii\web\Application::EVENT_BEFORE_REQUEST, function(yii\base\Event $event){
    $event->sender->response->on(yii\web\Response::EVENT_BEFORE_SEND, function($e){
        ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
    });
    $event->sender->response->on(yii\web\Response::EVENT_AFTER_SEND, function($e){
        ob_end_flush();
    });
});
$application->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following rules to .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
                                  "application/javascript" \
                                  "application/json" \
                                  "application/ld+json" \
                                  "application/manifest+json" \
                                  "application/rdf+xml" \
                                  "application/rss+xml" \
                                  "application/schema+json" \
                                  "application/vnd.geo+json" \
                                  "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" \
                                  "application/x-font-ttf" \
                                  "application/x-javascript" \
                                  "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" \
                                  "application/xhtml+xml" \
                                  "application/xml" \
                                  "font/eot" \
                                  "font/opentype" \
                                  "image/bmp" \
                                  "image/svg+xml" \
                                  "image/vnd.microsoft.icon" \
                                  "image/x-icon" \
                                  "text/cache-manifest" \
                                  "text/css" \
                                  "text/html" \
                                  "text/javascript" \
                                  "text/plain" \
                                  "text/vcard" \
                                  "text/vnd.rim.location.xloc" \
                                  "text/vtt" \
                                  "text/x-component" \
                                  "text/x-cross-domain-policy" \
                                  "text/xml"

</IfModule>
```

Configuration list: https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs